# Find the indices of last occurrence of the unique elements in a vector

Tags: r

I have an unordered vector `v` like the one shown below and would like to find the indices of the last occurrence of every unique elements in the list.

```
v <- scan(text="1 2 1 2 1 1 1 3 1 2 2 3 3 3 1 1 1 4 1 1 1 4 1 5 5 6
                6 2 3 3 4 4 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 1 4 4 4 3 2 5 5 5 5")
v
# [1] 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 3 1 2 2 3 3 3 1 1 1 4 1 1 1 4 1 5 5 6 6 2 3 3 4 4 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 
# [41] 1 4 4 4 3 2 5 5 5 5
```

Expected result (in order of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5):

```
41 46 45 44 50
```

I know I can use `unique(unlist(v))` to find the unique elements but then how to find the indices of their last appearance? Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you are calling a `list` looks like a `vector`. It is helpful if you use the correct terminology when asking questions since that would impact the answers. Also, as @akrun indicated, it's also best if you could share some sample data in a more reproducible form (`dput` is handy for that).

Comment: If elements are unique, what's the point of talking about the last occurrence? What you mean to say is finding the last occurrence of each (distinct) value that occurs in the vector.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Another approach that works even if the data are not ordered:

```
length(v1)-match(unique(v1),rev(v1))+1
```

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for :) Perfect. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11):

```
tapply(seq_along(v), v, max)
#  1  2  3  4  5  6 
# 41 46 45 44 50 27
```

Answer (score 8):

You could try `rle` if the `vector` is already ordered.  Extract the lengths (`$lengths)` and then `cumsum`.  As I mentioned earlier, this will not work if it is not ordered (again it depends on what you really wanted).  Basically `rle` works by checking the number of consecutive elements that are similar on a stretch.  It will give the `lengths` and corresponding `values` in a list.

```
cumsum(rle(v1)$lengths)
#[1] 28 37 42 46 50
```

Another option is to group the sequence by the vector and get the `max` value for each `group`.  I would imagine this to be slow.

```
unname(cumsum(tapply(seq_along(v1),v1, FUN=which.max)))    
#[1] 28 37 42 46 50
```

Or just check whether the previous value is the same as the current value and then insert `TRUE` as the last element, and get the index of `TRUE` with `which`

```
 which(c(v1[-1]!=v1[-length(v1)],TRUE))
 #[1] 28 37 42 46 50
```

Or use `match`

```
 c(match(unique(v1),v1)-1, length(v1))[-1]
#[1] 28 37 42 46 50
```

Or use `findInterval`

```
 findInterval(unique(v1), v1)
 #[1] 28 37 42 46 50
```

#### Update

For the new vector `v2`

```
max.col(t(sapply(unique(v2), `==`, v2)),'last')
#[1] 41 46 45 44 50 27
```

Or a function using `findInterval` after `ordering` the unordered vector

```
   f1 <- function(v){
      v1 <- setNames(v, seq_along(v))
      ind <- order(v1)
      as.numeric(names(v1[ind][findInterval(unique(v1), v1[ind])]))
    }     

 f1(v2)
 #[1] 41 46 45 44 50 27
```

Using the example (`z`) from @Marat talipov's post,

```
 f1(z)
 #[1] 4 5 3
```

NOTE: I get the result in the order in which the unique elements first appeared in `z`.  i.e. `1`, followed by `3`, `2`.  If it needs to be ordered again based on the values, it can be done using `order` (as mentioned by @Marat Talipov).  However, it is not clear what the OP really wanted in such situations.

#### data

```
v1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5)

v2 <-  c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 
 1, 4, 1, 5, 5, 6, 6, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 
 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5)

 z <- c(1, 3, 2, 1, 3)
```

Comment: All of the above worked !! Thanks a lot :)
Could you please explain how rle worked here?
And actually my list will not be sequential it can be like 1 1 2 3 3 2 4 5 1 2 1 1 3 3 4 2 5 5
I'll be editing my question as well.

Comment: @jmkam In that case, what will be the result you expected?

Comment: I've edited the list as unordered. And thanks for the explanations those are really helpful to understand.

Comment: max.col(t(sapply(unique(v2), `==`, v2)),'last') worked perfectly and this is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @jmkam When you post an example, it is better to mimic the data, otherwise, there are many possible scenarios, solutions etc..

Answer (score 7):

Also could try

```
which(c(diff(tmp), TRUE) == 1)
# [1] 28 37 42 46 50
```

Or similarly

```
which(!!c(diff(tmp), TRUE))
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try using `.N` from "data.table", like this:

```
library(data.table)
data.table(x, y = seq_along(x))[, y[.N], by = x]
#    x V1
# 1: 1 41
# 2: 2 46
# 3: 3 45
# 4: 4 44
# 5: 5 50
# 6: 6 27
```

Here, we basically create a two-column `data.table` where the first column is your vector, and the second is the index position of your vector. `.N` tells us how many rows are in each group (captured with `by =`), so we can just subset the values from `y` directly using that information.

---

Better yet, as recommended by @Arun, we can skip creating "y" and directly do:

```
data.table(x)[, .I[.N], by=x]
```

Sample data:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 
  1, 4, 1, 5, 5, 6, 6, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 
  4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5)
```

Answer (score 5):

I am sorry to say that but **the accepted answer, as well as several other answers that are supposed to work on the unordered vectors, provide incorrect solution**.

**[EDIT2]**

This answer have become a matter of controversy of what should be treated as a 'right' or 'wrong' answer. Herein, I interpreted the desired output as that a solution should be an unnamed vector ordered along the increasing order of unique elements. It turned out that other interpretations might exist (see comments below), and although they don't look very obvious to me, they definitely have right to exist, at least until OP adds more examples to clarify the situation

In this light, it might be better to say that **"the answers, which reproduce the OP's sample, might lead to inconsistent results on other input data sets with respect to the ordering of elements in the output vector"**. The inconsistency partly arose from the fact that the original OP's question was changed a couple of times, and the answers, which were perfectly fine at the current state of the question, might not work for the final state of the question. My answer is supposed to aware readers about this situation, and to suggest the easy fix to obtain the solution for the final state of the OP's question.

Finally, I do realize that my answer turned out to be a huge overkill but, given the level of confusion in the post, I think it is better to clarify the situation for future interested readers.

**/[EDIT2]**

I have discovered the problem accidentally, when I started putting different solutions together to play with a benchmarking study. Some solutions mentioned here don't work because the original question implicated that the input vector is sorted in the increasing order, which turned out to be not the case, so I don't discuss them here. The solutions that provide the right answers on the author's example data set were collected together and wrapped in the corresponding functions:

```
f.duplicated <- function(z) {
  i <- which(!duplicated(z,fromLast=T))
  i[order(z[i])]  
}

f.match.unique.rev <- function(v1) {
  length(v1)-match(unique(v1),rev(v1))+1
}

f.max.col.sapply.unique <- function(v2){
  max.col(t(sapply(unique(v2), `==`, v2)),'last')
}

f.data.table <- function(x) {
  # data.table(x, y = seq_along(x))[, y[.N], by = x]$V1
  setkey(data.table(x, y = seq_along(x)), x)[, y[.N], by = x]$V1
}

f.tapply.seq_along.max <- function(v) {
  tapply(seq_along(v), v, max)
}

f.sapply.split.seq_along.max <- function(v) {
  sapply(split(seq_along(v), v), max)
}
```

Then, I wrote a small function to compare the results:

```
compare.results <- function(z) {
  d <- rbind(
    f.duplicated(z),
    f.match.unique.rev(z),
    f.max.col.sapply.unique(z),
    f.data.table(z),
    f.tapply.seq_along.max(z),
    f.sapply.split.seq_along.max(z)
    )
  rownames(d) <- c(
    'f.duplicated',
    'f.match.unique.rev',
    'f.max.col.sapply.unique',
    'f.data.table',
    'f.tapply.seq_along.max',
    'f.sapply.split.seq_along.max'
  )
  d
}
```

and made sure that the selected solution work on the exemplary data:

```
z <- c(1,2,1,2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 5, 5, 6, 6, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5)

compare.results(z)
#                               1  2  3  4  5  6
# f.duplicated                 41 46 45 44 50 27
# f.match.unique.rev           41 46 45 44 50 27
# f.max.col.sapply.unique      41 46 45 44 50 27
# f.data.table                 41 46 45 44 50 27
# f.tapply.seq_along.max       41 46 45 44 50 27
# f.sapply.split.seq_along.max 41 46 45 44 50 27
```

**[PROBLEM]** when I used another input vector `1 3 2 1 3`, for which the right answer is `4 3 5`, I found that some solutions provide the wrong result:

```
z <- c(1,3,2,1,3)
compare.results(z)
#                              1 2 3
# f.duplicated                 4 3 5
# f.match.unique.rev           4 5 3  # ***
# f.max.col.sapply.unique      4 5 3  # ***
# f.data.table                 4 3 5
# f.tapply.seq_along.max       4 3 5
# f.sapply.split.seq_along.max 4 3 5
```

**[FIX]** I figured out that the problem with the `f.match.unique.rev` (accepted answer) and `f.max.col.sapply.unique` solutions lies in the implication that unique elements have the increasing order in the data set, which is the case in the author's example, but not in the my example. Here are the fixed solutions:

```
f.max.col.sapply.unique <- function(v2){
  i <- max.col(t(sapply(unique(v2), `==`, v2)),'last')
  i[order(v2[i])]  
}


f.match.unique.rev <- function(v1) {
  i <- length(v1)-match(unique(v1),rev(v1))+1
  i[order(v1[i])]  
}
```

**[EDIT]** I was informed that the original `f.data.table` result--which was a data.table structure with two columns (`x` and `V1`)--contains all information needed to construct the answer in the format that was expected by the author of the question. In fact, the mistake in `f.data.table` was introduced by my decision to use the column `V1` as the function output. I updated `f.data.table` by a modified code (see comment below) that provides the correct solution in the expected format, and saved the old version as a comment. Besides, I removed the discussion of the `f.data.table` solution from the end of my answer, as it is not needed any longer.

Comment: You are right !! Indeed I sort the initial output in descending order at the very next line of my code.

Comment: It's hard to say that the answers are "incorrect". For example, in my "data.table" answer, I output a table so that it's easy to match the value with the position. If a vector is all that were required, I would probably take a different approach, for example, using `setkey` in the answer (`setkey(data.table(x, y = seq_along(x)), x)[, y[.N], by = x]$V1`). I don't know if the other answers are affected by similar assumptions.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, I used in 'incorrect solution' in a strict sense that the output is different from the author's expected result. However, I overlooked that your original solution comes together with the indices, so it provides enough information to infer the correct answer. It was rather my mistake to use one column from your solution as a final result, and I will edit my answer accordingly. The other answers are not affected by this issue.

Comment: Just FYI, OP changed his data and desired ouput quite a few times and its not our duty to check in here every hour in order to see if there are new requests.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I agree that the dynamically changing requirements created a total mess in this post. However, the future readers will be unaware of this situation, and they might want to know that some answers, including the accepted one, don't provide the solution that they could expect from the question.

Comment: @MaratTalipov We don't know how the OP wants to get the sequence.  If it is in the order as it occurs in `z`, my output is correct or else if he wants to again reorder it based on the order of unique elements, it yours will be

Comment: @MaratTalipov I do think that in this situation, calling other solutions are `incorrect` is wrong.

Comment: @akrun, the OP expects the result to be an unnamed vector in order of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, which means that a solution should be ordered along the increasing order of unique elements (please correct me if it still sounds ambiguous).

Comment: I did read that part `Expected result (in order of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5):`, but here, the order is aligning with the order of elements.  If the OP had provided an example like yours and said `I wanted the result to be in this way`, it would have been better.  Based on how we interpret, you could call other solution as incorrect, and viceversa.

Comment: @MaratTalipov  Anyway, it is just an order issue.  If I can show the corresponding index value, this is a minor problem..

Comment: @akrun and David Arenburg, thank you for your comments. I have refined my answer according to your suggestions

Answer (score 4):

Here is another approach:

```
z <- c(1,2,1,2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 5, 5, 6, 6, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5)

i <- which(!duplicated(z,fromLast=T))
i[order(z[i])]
```

`duplicated` returns a logical vector indicating duplicates, considered from the reverse side. The idea is to take an inverse of this vector to obtain logical vector of unique elements, and to use `which` to obtain the indices.

UPDATE:
As noted in the comment, my original answer `which(!duplicated(z,fromLast=T))` returned a vector that did not correspond to the increasing order of elements in the input vector. To fix that issue, I saved the result from the first command as vector `i` and reordered it as needed.

Comment: For a given 
t <- c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 5, 4)
the expected result should be like below for elements 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
11  6  8 13 12
But the code above returns it in a different order as
6  8 11 12 13

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun,

```
library(dplyr)  
#you can use new feature `add_rownames()`   
data.frame(x, row=1:length(x)) %>% group_by(x) %>%  summarise(max(row))
#  x max(row)
#1 1       41
#2 2       46
#3 3       45
#4 4       44
#5 5       50
#6 6       27
```

for

```
x <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 
  1, 4, 1, 5, 5, 6, 6, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 
  4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun - not vectorized - but does the job:

```
sapply(split(seq_along(v), v), max)
# 1  2  3  4  5  6 
#41 46 45 44 50 27
```

Answer (score 2):

With the `grouping` function:

```
g <- grouping(v)
g[attr(g, "ends")]
# [1] 41 46 45 44 50 27
```

Comment: Nice built-in function! I didn't know that. Thanks.